# Left join returning both more and less rows after query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am a newbie to SQL and I would like to ask for help. I have 2 tables which I want to join and I would like to generate the same number of rows that table 1 has.

Here are the tables:

Table 1

```
+----------+------------+---------+-------+
| ENTRY_ID | ROUTE_NAME | STATION | BOUND |
+----------+------------+---------+-------+
|        1 |         1A |    ABCC |     1 |
|        2 |         2C |    CBDD |     1 |
|        3 |          5 |    AAAA |     2 |
|        4 |         1A |    EEEE |     1 |
|        5 |         2B |    ASFA |     2 |
|        6 |          5 |    DSAS |     1 |
|        7 |          3 |    QWEA |     2 |
|        8 |          4 |    ASDA |     1 |
+----------+------------+---------+-------+
```

Table 2

```
+------------+-------+---------+---------------+
| ROUTE_NAME | BOUND | STATION | STOP_SEQUENCE |
+------------+-------+---------+---------------+
|         1A |     1 |     AAA |             1 |  
|         1A |     1 |     ABC |             2 |
|         1A |     1 |     CDA |             3 |
|         1A |     2 |     ABC |             1 |
|         1A |     2 |     ADC |             2 |
|         1A |     2 |     ACA |             3 |
```

Repeated for other Routes

Short description for the Table:
`Table 1` contains certain transit trips, with transit route to be taken as `ROUTE_NAME`, departure stop as `STATION` and transit bound as `BOUND` (only 1/2).
`Table 2` contains a set of transit route data, with similar field to Table 1 and the sequence of stop as `STOP_SEQUENCE`

What I would like to do, is to use `STATION`, `BOUND` and `ROUTE_NAME` IN Table 1 to call for `STOP_SEQUENCE` in Table 2. The code that I have used is :

```
SELECT t1.ENTRY_ID, t1.ROUTE_NAME, t1.STATION, t1.BOUND, t2.STOP_SEQUENCE
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN t2 ON 
(t1.STATION LIKE '*' & t2.STATION & '*') AND
(t1.BOUND = t2.BOUND) AND
(t1.ROUTE_NAME = t2.ROUTE_NAME);
```

The LIKE is a must as there is some mismatch between the STATION string of the 2 tables, that can be handled by the function.

The **first** question is, why does the LEFT JOIN not return all rows from TABLE 1? I have a similar code that works in other similar tables. For the data that didn't match up (with the LIKE statement), NULL is returned for that particular row. However, in this query less rows are returned.

The **second** question is, with the LIKE statement I am returning one or more rows from table 2 from table 1 which matches my criteria (that has happened in my code that 2+ rows with same `ENTRY_ID` has been returned). How can I keep the minimum of the returned row? i.e. if two `STOP_SEQUENCE` is found, return the lower one.

Have struggled for this for a long time so many thanks for your help!

**UPDATE**
I have found that the sentence `t1.STATION LIKE '*' & t2.STATION & '*'` is causing the lack of rows as in the first question. I have replaced it with = and all rows came up again. However I still need this LIKE clause, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the LEFT JOIN not return all rows from TABLE 1?

I could only suspect this is an issue with your testing since the SQL code posted in your question will return the values held by columns `t1.ENTRY_ID`, `t1.ROUTE_NAME`, `t1.STATION`, & `t1.BOUND` for all records in your table `t1`, and the value of `t2.STOP_SEQUENCE` for all records in your table `t2` which fulfil the join criteria for *each* record in your table `t1`.

Note that this will return multiple records from table `t2` if more than one record fulfils the join criteria for a given record in table `t1`. Which leads to your next question:

> With the LIKE statement I am returning one or more rows from table 2 from table 1 which matches my criteria (that has happened in my code that 2+ rows with same ENTRY_ID has been returned). How can I keep the minimum of the returned row? i.e. if two STOP_SEQUENCE is found, return the lower one.

You can achieve this with simple aggregation using the `min` function:

```
select
    t1.entry_id,
    t1.route_name,
    t1.station, 
    t1.bound,
    min(t2.stop_sequence) as stopseq
from
    t1 left join t2 on
    t1.station like '*' & t2.station & '*' and
    t1.bound = t2.route_bound and
    t1.route_name = t2.route_name
group by
    t1.entry_id,
    t1.route_name,
    t1.station, 
    t1.bound
```

This will return the minimum value held by the field `t2.stop_sequence` within the group defined by each combination of values held by `t1.entry_id`, `t1.route_name`, `t1.station`, & `t1.bound`.

---

Aside, note that the sample table `t2` in your question does not contain the field `route_bound` as referenced by your posted code.

Comment: Your code works perfect for me, thanks! However, based on the code here, how can I also include entries that are not meeting the requirements of t1.station like '*' & t2.station & '*', and return 0 as stop_seq?

Comment: You can change `t2.stop_sequence` to `Nz(t2.stop_sequence, 0)` to return `0` for a null value.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, let me describe the situation here. For my question one I got 100,000 rows instead of 140,000 rows. After using your code, I get 100,000 rows but some of the rows contain NULL value that does not meet the LIKE requirement. After the update with Nz(), the NULL value are changed to 0. It seems to me that the core of the issue lies in Question 1, which I have yet to find a solution for that

Comment: And, I have tested by removing the LIKE statement from my code, and all 140,000 entries came back. However I see no problem in that LIKE statement.